# How to find the parent of a file by inode

Tags: linux, shell, directory-structure, inode

I want to use ntfsundelete to maintain the directory structure of the recovered files. The output of ntfsundelete is like this:

```
Inode    Flags  %age  Date            Size  Filename
191321   FN..   100%  2016-04-26      1175  file.txt
191322   D...   100%  2016-04-26        10  my directory
```

The output doesn't show the full path of 'file.txt', just its inode.
So, how can I find the inode of its parent directory?

Answer (score 2):

Inodes don't have parent information, that is why directory entry and inodes are separate. It's directory entries (or dentry) which have parents.

The reason for above is to support hardlinks. Since hardlinks point to the same inode, they can be under different directories(parents).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `--parent` parameter, as described in the `ntfsundelete` man page?

Since it was able to find the information from the folder that initially included it, that should normally work.

Comment: Yes, I tried the --parameter, but it just displays the **name** of the parent directory. This makes some confusion as the same name may be used for different parent directories inside the root directory but at different levels such as (/media/new-files and /media/gadgets/new-files). The files inside both of them would appear as if they belong to the **same** parent directory. This is why I need the inode (of the absolute path) of the parent not just its name.

Answer (score 0):

[Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=53) has a utility called `ntfsundeleteall` which is described as

> a simple wrapper for the utility 'ntfsundelete' ... it prepends the
>   original inode (=internal number for the file on the filesystem)
>   before the filename, so you always have a unique filename. It's up to
>   you to rename the files afterwards, but at least you have the original
>   name in the recovered filename.

You can use it by downloading the TRK disk and booting from it.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to find the source of this wrapper script.  It's not hard to imagine a bash script which would create folders based on the iNode names reported by `ntfsundelete --scan`, maybe even make optimistic guesses about files and folders based on consecutive iNode numbers... But it's hard to write it, and I can't find anybody who has.

Comment: The _ntfsundeleteall_ utility doesn't recover the full path, too. As described at its page:
It 's a good utility that recovers your files with the original filename **but without the relevant path in front**.

Comment: You're right.  I've just written a script which attempts to make some intelligent guesses at the answer.  I'll push it to GitHub then make another answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find(1)`, eg :

```
find ./ -inum 191321
```

Might be a bit slow, though.

Comment: _ntfsundelete_ works only on unmounted partitions. So, you cannot use _find_. Furthermore, even if you mounted the target partition, _find_ would find nothing as the file no longer exists in the inode table.